# Share Image and text on facebook wall in iphone is not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

**hello Guys, I want to share image directly in iphone and share text also .
I have implemented the following code on button click but it is doing nothing...**

```
     NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];

 [variables setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi... Testing APp"] forKey:@"message"];
 [variables setObject:@"http://icon.png" forKey:@"picture"];       //http://tinyurl.com/45xy4kw
 [variables setObject:@"Create post" forKey:@"name"];
 [variables setObject:@"Write description." forKey:@"description"];

 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" andParams:variables andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

**I m using facebook direct api for this
[Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/)**

Comment: FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables]; remove "/" before me

Answer (score 2):

Use this code its working fine

```
-(IBAction)postMeFeedButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:8];


    //create a UIImage (you could use the picture album or camera too)
    UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon@2x.png"];

    //create a FbGraphFile object insance and set the picture we wish to publish on it
    FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];

    //finally, set the FbGraphFileobject onto our variables dictionary....
    [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

    NSArray *idarry=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:Delegate.IdListArray];
    NSLog(@"Delegate array %@",Delegate.IdListArray);

    //NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"100001912715296,100001912715296"];
    NSString *str=[idarry componentsJoinedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"The string contents are %@",str);

   NSString *idstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"100002875785051,100001912715296"];

    [variables setObject:idstr forKey:@"tags"];
    [variables setObject:@"110506962309835" forKey:@"place"];

    [variables setObject:@"Hello All my dear friends,I am using MySafety APP" forKey:@"message"];
    [variables setObject:@"http://techilasolutions.com/product.html" forKey:@"link"];
    [variables setObject:@"My Safety" forKey:@"name"];
    [variables setObject:@"http://techilasolutions.com/images/car_tag.png" forKey:@"picture"];
    [variables setObject:@"This is a must have app for all women whether you are a working lady, a house wife or a school going girl.This app lets you save 6 emergency contacts whom you want to alert in case of emergency.Whenever you feel you are in danger, just press the SOS button and it will send sms to your contacts with your current location and a alarm will go on with flashing lights" forKey:@"description"];

    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
    NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

    //parse our json
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *facebook_response = [parser objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];
    [parser release];

    //let's save the 'id' Facebook gives us so we can delete it if the user presses the 'delete /me/feed button'
    self.feedPostId = (NSString *)[facebook_response objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"feedPostId, %@", feedPostId);
    NSLog(@"Now log into Facebook and look at your profile...");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post image using this code try this code once.

```
-(IBAction)postPictureButtonPressed:(id)sender 
  {
     NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

     UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"75x75.png"];

     FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];

     [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

     [variables setObject:@"this is a test message: postPictureButtonPressed" forKey:@"message"];

     FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"117795728310/photos" withPostVars:variables];
     NSLog(@"postPictureButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

     NSLog(@"Now log into Facebook and look at your profile & photo albums...");

   }
```

Comment: I have tried this also it is also not working I dunno wt is the problem comming...!

Comment: are you add FB Graph Api folder .

Comment: No, I do not want to add any api.. ! I have to implement direct facebook api only..